# Mac Apache document root weird behavior

Tags: apache, laravel, localhost, document-root

I have a Laravel 5.4 project installed in my macOS Sierra localhost located in /Library/Webserver/Documents/project/ but when I access http: //localhost/project/admin/ in the web browser, it will take me to http: //localhost/admin. It is not reading the project directory.

When I also use ajax request, it will be directed to a wrong url also.

```
$.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: "/users/change-password",
   data: {id: id},
   dataType: "json",
})
```

This ajax call will go to: 
[request url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3LBO.png)

I think its because of some configuration that was changed when I tried different .htaccess files but I'm not sure with that also.

Comment: What is the content of your .htaccess file? Do you have a virtual host for your project, what is the config for that?

Comment: I did not change the default .htaccess in /project/public/.htaccess. I think I don't have a virtual host, I followed the instructions here: 
https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-on-macos-sierra/ 
before installing the laravel project to my localhost.